# Including an Image with LaTeX when the path is stored within a variable

Tags: graphics

I have a LaTeX document and I want to include an image. If I use:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{protocol_images/flake/arrangement_classes/14-1-11}
```

everything works perfectly fine. However, if the image path is stored inside a variable, it doesn't work. Why? Here's the code:

```
%Concatenating strings to a path
\def\ImgPath{\ImgDirPath}
\global\edef\ImgPath{\ImgPath14-1-11}

%Using the path
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\ImgPath}
```

Here's the error:

> File `protocol\T1\textunderscoreimages/flake/arrangement\T1\textunderscoreclasses/14-1-11' not found. ...ludegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\ImgPath}}

If I print the `\Imgpath` variable I get the following (so it works...):

[image]

An alternative which I tried is:

```
\boxed{\tikz \node (pic) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\ImgPath}}
```

but it's also not working and throws the same error.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Please always provide full but minimal examples. It makes testing a lot easier. You never specify what `\ImgDirPath` is so we cannot be 100% sure as to what exactly you are doing.

Comment: OK, thank you very much - sounds reasonable. Problem was that I had backslashes before the underscores in the ImgDirPath variable. I removed it and now everything works fine. Just didn't understood this error message....